# Using Pentaho Report Designer how to display data in a line

Tags: database, formatting, reporting, pentaho

Using Pentaho Report Designer I want to take data from columns in a database and have this data displayed in a line.

See my example below. Is there a way I can accomplish this?

My database table looks like this:

```
GENUS       SPECIFIC_EPITHET    SPECIES_AUTHOR
Asplenium   scolopendrium       L.
Asplenium   bradleyi            D.C. Eaton
Asplenium   platyneuron        (L.) Britton, Sterns & Poggenb.
Asplenium   viride              Huds.
```

I would like the report to look like this:

```
Asplenium scolopendrium L., Asplenium bradleyi D.C. Eaton, Asplenium platyneuron (L.) Britton, Sterns & Poggenb., Asplenium viride Huds.
```

I am only able to get the report to show the data in a column like list as shown below.

```
Asplenium scolopendrium L.
Asplenium bradleyi D.C. Eaton
Asplenium platyneuron (L.) Britton, Sterns & Poggenb.
Asplenium viride Huds.
```

It would also be helpful if someone would tell me if this is not possible in PRD.

Comment: whats the database you use?

Comment: I am using pgAdmin with a PostgreSQL database but I don't think this should matter.

Answer (score 0):

I figured this out thanks to being shown how by Deanicus on the Pentaho Reporting Forum ([see here](http://forums.pentaho.com/showthread.php?162730-line-up-data-in-a-line-vs-a-column)).

The main trick was to query my database before I got my data into the report via PRD. Since I am working with a POSTGRESQL database the code I used to query the database looked something like this.

```
SELECT
     string_agg(CONCAT(CONCAT(CONCAT(
     c."genus", ' '),
     c."specific_epithet",' '),
     c."species_author"),', ') as scinamewauthor
FROM
     "public"."main_checklist" as c
```

My final query was actually a lot more complicated since I was adding all sorts of spaces and html formatting marks. The entire piece of code actually looks like this.

```
SELECT
    string_agg (CONCAT(
     (SELECT CASE WHEN s."genus_synonym" IS NULL THEN '' ELSE '<i>'||s."genus_synonym"||'</i>' END),
     (SELECT CASE WHEN s."specific_epithet_synonym" IS NULL THEN '' ELSE ' <i>'||s."specific_epithet_synonym"||'</i>' END),
     (SELECT CASE WHEN s."species_author_synonym" IS NULL THEN '' ELSE ' '||s."species_author_synonym" END),
     (SELECT CASE WHEN s."subspecific_epithet_synonym" IS NULL THEN '' ELSE ' ssp. '||'<i>'||s."subspecific_epithet_synonym"||'</i>'END),
     (SELECT CASE WHEN s."subspecies author_synonym" IS NULL THEN '' ELSE ' '|| s."subspecies author_synonym" END),
     (SELECT CASE WHEN s."varietal_epithet_synonym" IS NULL THEN '' ELSE ' var. <i>'||s."varietal_epithet_synonym"||'</i>'    END),
     (SELECT CASE WHEN s."variety_author_synonym" IS NULL THEN '' ELSE ' '|| s."variety_author_synonym" END),
     (SELECT CASE WHEN s."misapplied" = 'misapplied hybrid formula 1' THEN ' misapplied' ELSE '' END),
     (SELECT CASE WHEN s."hybrid_formula_genus_synonym" is null THEN '' ELSE ' × <i>'||substring("hybrid_formula_genus_synonym" from 1 for 1)||'.</i>'END),
     (SELECT CASE WHEN s."hybrid_formula_specific_epithet_synonym" is null THEN '' ELSE ' <i>'|| s."hybrid_formula_specific_epithet_synonym"||'</i>' END),
     (SELECT CASE WHEN s."hybrid_formula_species_author_synonym" is null THEN '' ELSE ' '||s."hybrid_formula_species_author_synonym" END),
     (SELECT CASE WHEN s."hybrid_formula_subspecific_epithet_synonym" IS NULL THEN '' ELSE ' ssp. <i>'||s."hybrid_formula_subspecific_epithet_synonym"||'</i>' END),
     (SELECT CASE WHEN s."hybrid_formula_subspecies_author_synonym" IS NULL THEN '' ELSE ' '||s."hybrid_formula_subspecies_author_synonym"  END),
     (SELECT CASE WHEN s."hybrid_formula_varietal_epithet_synonym" IS NULL THEN '' ELSE ' var. <i>'||s."hybrid_formula_varietal_epithet_synonym"||'</i>'END),
     (SELECT CASE WHEN s."hybrid_formula_variety_author_synonym" IS NULL THEN '' ELSE ' '||s."hybrid_formula_variety_author_synonym"END),
     (SELECT CASE WHEN s."misapplied" = 'misapplied hybrid formula 2' THEN ' misapplied' ELSE '' END),
     (SELECT CASE WHEN s."genus_hybrid_synonym" IS NULL THEN '' ELSE '×'End),
     (SELECT CASE   WHEN s."hybrid_name_genus_synonym" IS NULL THEN '' 
                WHEN s."genus_synonym" IS NULL THEN '<i>'||s."hybrid_name_genus_synonym"||'</i>' 
                Else ' = <i>'||"hybrid_name_genus_synonym" ||'</i>'END),
     (SELECT CASE   WHEN s."hybrid_name_specific_epithet_synonym" IS NULL THEN '' 
                when s."genus_hybrid_synonym" is null then ' ×<i>'||s."hybrid_name_specific_epithet_synonym"||'</i>' 
                ELSE ' <i>'||s."hybrid_name_specific_epithet_synonym"||'</i>' END),
     (SELECT CASE WHEN s."hybrid_name_species_author_synonym" IS NULL THEN '' ELSE ' '||s."hybrid_name_species_author_synonym" END),
     (SELECT CASE WHEN s."hybrid_name_subspecific_epithet_synonym" IS NULL THEN '' ELSE ' ssp. <i>'||s."hybrid_name_subspecific_epithet_synonym"||'</i>'END),
     (SELECT CASE WHEN s."hybrid_name_subspecies_author_synonym" IS NULL THEN '' ELSE ' '||s."hybrid_name_subspecies_author_synonym"END),
     (SELECT CASE WHEN s."hybrid_name_varietal_epithet_synonym" IS NULL THEN '' ELSE ' var. <i>'||s."hybrid_name_varietal_epithet_synonym"||'</i>'END),
     (SELECT CASE WHEN s."hybrid_name_variety_author_synonym" IS NULL THEN '' ELSE ' 'END),
     s."hybrid_name_variety_author_synonym",
     (SELECT CASE   WHEN (s."misapplied" IS NULL or s."misapplied" = 'misapplied hybrid formula 1' or s."misapplied" = 'misapplied hybrid formula 2') Then '' 
                WHEN s."misapplied" = 'misapplied hybrid name' Then ' misapplied'
                Else ' '||"misapplied" END)),
     ', '
     Order by s."genus_synonym" ASC,
     s."specific_epithet_synonym" ASC,
     s."varietal_epithet_synonym" ASC NULLS FIRST,
     s."subspecific_epithet_synonym" ASC NULLS FIRST,
     s."hybrid_formula_specific_epithet_synonym" ASC,
     s."hybrid_formula_subspecific_epithet_synonym" ASC,
     s."hybrid_formula_varietal_epithet_synonym" ASC,
     s."hybrid_name_specific_epithet_synonym" ASC)as syno


FROM

     "public"."synonyms" as s INNER JOIN "public"."main_checklist" ON s."record_id" = "public"."main_checklist"."record_id"
WHERE
    s."record_id" = ${import_record_id}
```